# Open window in C# class library project

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, class-library

I am still new and learning C# as I go. My question is generic, so let me know if I can be more specific in any way. I am moreover looking for guidance/examples to go off of or even a simple solution to build from.

I have a class library that is currently working, but I want to display a window to the user. My class is for a program called Solidworks PDM and is a menu command. In the middle, I need the user to review and select "OK" or "Cancel".

Basically, how do I get a window that contains two buttons "OK" and "Cancel" in the my class library? Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EdmLib;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1 : IEdmAddIn5
    {
        public void GetAddInInfo(ref EdmAddInInfo poInfo, IEdmVault5 poVault, IEdmCmdMgr5 poCmdMgr)
        {
            //Specify information to display in the add-in's Properties dialog box   
            poInfo.mbsAddInName = "Menu command sample";
            poInfo.mbsCompany = "SOLIDWORKS Corporation";
            poInfo.mbsDescription = "Adds menu command items";
            poInfo.mlAddInVersion = 1;
            //Specify the minimum required version of SOLIDWORKS Enterprise PDM  
            poInfo.mlRequiredVersionMajor = 10;
            poInfo.mlRequiredVersionMinor = 0;
            //Register a menu command  
            poCmdMgr.AddCmd(100, "Inspection Request (New C#)", (int)EdmMenuFlags.EdmMenu_OnlySingleSelection);
        }
        public void OnCmd(ref EdmCmd poCmd, ref Array ppoData)
        {
            if (poCmd.meCmdType == EdmCmdType.EdmCmd_Menu) //This makes sure the addin was called on a menu right click  
            {
                if (poCmd.mlCmdID == 100) //This makes sure the menu command ID was 100, which means your addin was the one called  
                {
                    //Let's get moving, it's our turn!  
                    IEdmVault12 myVault = (IEdmVault12)poCmd.mpoVault; //Cast the vault to an Iedmvault12 object for latest functionality  
                    string Mymessage = null;//instantiate a string message  
                    //string StrID = null;//instantiate the ID of the object  
                    if ((((EdmCmdData)ppoData.GetValue(0)).mlObjectID1) != 0) //mlObjectID1 will be 0 if a folder was selected and the ID of the file if a file was selected during a menu command  
                    {
                        //Mymessage = Mymessage + "File: (ID=";
                        IEdmFile5 myfile = (IEdmFile10)myVault.GetObject(EdmObjectType.EdmObject_File, (((EdmCmdData)ppoData.GetValue(0)).mlObjectID1));//Get the file object  

                        string fileNoExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myfile.Name);

                        IEdmEnumeratorVariable10 myvars = default(IEdmEnumeratorVariable10); //Set the enumeratorvariable object  
                        myvars = (IEdmEnumeratorVariable10)myfile.GetEnumeratorVariable(); //Cast the enumeratorvariable object to the file  
                        object CreatedBy = null; //Create a variable to hold the model no.  
                        object Desc1 = null;
                        object Desc2 = null;
                        object Rev = null;

                        myvars.GetVar("CreatedBy", "@", out CreatedBy); //Use the GetVar method  
                        myvars.GetVar("CAD_Description", "@", out Desc1);
                        myvars.GetVar("CAD_Description1", "@", out Desc2);
                        myvars.GetVar("CAD_Revision", "@", out Rev);

                        myvars.CloseFile(false); //Always close the file when done accessing card variables to avoid runtime errors  
                                                 //Mymessage = Mymessage + "File ID: " + myfile.ID + System.Environment.NewLine; //Create a message with the File ID  

                        Mymessage = Mymessage + "CreatedBy: " + CreatedBy + System.Environment.NewLine; //Add the model no. variable  
                        Mymessage = Mymessage + "Description: " + Desc1 + System.Environment.NewLine;
                        Mymessage = Mymessage + "Description1: " + Desc2 + System.Environment.NewLine;
                        Mymessage = Mymessage + "Revision: " + Rev + System.Environment.NewLine;

                        MessageBox.Show(Mymessage); //Show the message box!  

                        MessageBox.Show("Get template path");
                        string templPath = @"C:\SeanVault\Templates\template.item.cvd";
                        string newPath = @"C:\SeanVault\Inspection Files";
                        string filename = fileNoExt + " Rev " + Rev.ToString() + ".insp";
                        IEdmFile5 templateFile = default(IEdmFile5);
                        IEdmFolder5 srcFolder = null;
                        templateFile = myVault.GetFileFromPath(templPath, out srcFolder);

                        MessageBox.Show("Get destination path");
                        IEdmFolder5 destFolder = default(IEdmFolder5);
                        destFolder = myVault.GetFolderFromPath(newPath);
                        if (destFolder == null)
                            return;


                        int fileID = 0;
                        fileID = destFolder.CopyFile(templateFile.ID, srcFolder.ID, 0, filename, (int)EdmCopyFlag.EdmCpy_Simple);

                        Interaction.MsgBox("Copied file successfully to new file with ID, " + fileID);


                        IEdmFile5 newFile = default(IEdmFile5);
                        IEdmFile5 itemFile = default(IEdmFile5);

                        newPath = newPath + "\\" + filename;

                        //Search for file with .item extension
                        IEdmSearch5 Search = default(IEdmSearch5);
                        Search = (IEdmSearch5)myVault.CreateUtility(EdmUtility.EdmUtil_Search);

                        Search.FindFiles = true;
                        //Search.StartFolderID = 102; //Regular Items ID
                        Search.FileName = fileNoExt + ".item";
                        IEdmSearchResult5 Result = default(IEdmSearchResult5);


                        Result = Search.GetFirstResult();
                        object StockingType = null; //Create a variable to hold the model no. 
                        if (Result != null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Result exists. Begin! Path = " + Result.Path);
                            itemFile = myVault.GetFileFromPath(Result.Path, out srcFolder);
                            IEdmEnumeratorVariable10 itemVars = default(IEdmEnumeratorVariable10); //Set the enumeratorvariable object  
                            itemVars = (IEdmEnumeratorVariable10)itemFile.GetEnumeratorVariable(); //Cast the enumeratorvariable object to the file  
                            //breaks
                            itemVars.GetVar("ITEM_StockingType", "", out StockingType); //Use the GetVar method  
                            //itemVars.GetVar("CAD_Description", "@", out Desc1);
                            //itemVars.GetVar("CAD_Description1", "@", out Desc2);
                            //itemVars.GetVar("CAD_Revision", "@", out Rev);
                            MessageBox.Show("5");
                            myvars.CloseFile(false); //Always close the file when done accessing card variables to avoid runtime errors  
                                                     //Mymessage = Mymessage + "File ID: " + myfile.ID + System.Environment.NewLine; //Create a message with the File ID  
                        }

                        newFile = myVault.GetFileFromPath(newPath, out srcFolder);
                        //update variables
                        IEdmEnumeratorVariable10 myNewVars = default(IEdmEnumeratorVariable10); //Set the enumeratorvariable object  
                        myNewVars = (IEdmEnumeratorVariable10)newFile.GetEnumeratorVariable(); //Cast the enumeratorvariable object to the file  

                        MessageBox.Show(Rev.ToString() + "," + StockingType.ToString());

                        myNewVars.SetVar("ITEM_RevisionNumber", "", Rev.ToString());
                        myNewVars.SetVar("ITEM_DescriptionLine1", "", Desc1.ToString());
                        myNewVars.SetVar("ITEM_DescriptionLine2", "", Desc2.ToString());

                        if (StockingType.ToString() != null)
                        {
                            myNewVars.SetVar("ITEM_StockingType", "", StockingType.ToString());
                        }

                        myvars.CloseFile(false); //Always close the file when done accessing card variables to avoid runtime errors  
                                                 //Mymessage = Mymessage + "File ID: " + myfile.ID + System.Environment.NewLine; //Create a message with the File ID  


                        //Check-in new file
                        newFile.UnlockFile(0,"Created and checked-in with Sean's API.");

                        //myvars.SetVar("CAD_Weight","@", "This Worked");

                        //Mymessage = Mymessage + "File name: " + ((EdmCmdData)ppoData.GetValue(0)).mbsStrData1 + System.Environment.NewLine; //Add the file name  

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: both wpf and winforms have MessageBox class

Comment: As you suggest in your tags, make it a WinForms project.

Comment: Libraries can contain forms. It's all just code and data. You use the exact same approach as with any other code that needs to show a window.

Comment: Read about it [here](http://help.solidworks.com/2014/English/api/epdmapi/Create_Custom_Card_View_Example_CSharp.htm). Also add title description that this is lib for solidworks to prevent -1.

Comment: @Logman I don't know anything about the Solidworks PDM library, do you know if there is there any reason my answer wouldn't work for it?

Comment: I need the project to be a class library. @logman I saw the example previously, but it simply edits the current winform. I was moreover looking to open a form or dialogue window where I can add the data card as the content. Can I use a messagebox that is adjusted? How would I go about that?

Comment: @SeanDon I'm not completely sure what your requirements are. Is there some code (and specific requirements) you can add to your question to give me some more context of what we're working with?

Comment: I'll do that shortly Blake. I need to get back to my desk first.

Comment: I added my code for reference. I'm performing a task where you create a file from a template and I wish to show the new file data card after variables have been populated.

Comment: I found this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) that gives me a dialogue in the class library code. I will try to add what I need into this.

Comment: Do you just need a window to pop up to retrieve this data... `string templPath = @"C:\SeanVault\Templates\template.item.cvd";
                        string newPath = @"C:\SeanVault\Inspection Files";` ? If so, I can help pretty easily with that; you'll need more than DialogResult. You'll need to create your own Form that can return a DialogResult.

Comment: @SeanDon Check my updated answer, I created a form for you to use to get the info you need, or at least the info I think you needed to get.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad your Form should work, OP should just show it when he need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create a Form that has input options for the user to interact with to get the file paths and such that you need. Based on the code you've given, I went ahead and made up what I think you need. It should be pretty close to what you actually use, but with this as a basis you should be able to edit it to your needs pretty easily.

The form with a File Selector and Folder Selector with OK and Cancel buttons...

```
public partial class RequestInfo : Form
{
    private Action<string, string> _sendValues = null;

    public RequestInfo(Action<string, string> retrieveValues)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _sendValues = retrieveValues;
    }

    private void fileBrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            filePath.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
    }

    private void folderBrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            folderPath.Text = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
    }

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _sendValues(filePath.Text, folderPath.Text);
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

An example of using the RequestInfo form...

```
public static partial class Program 
{
    private static string _filePath = "";
    private static string _folderPath = "";

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        RequestInfo infoForm = new RequestInfo(assignValues);
        DialogResult result = infoForm.ShowDialog();

        if (result.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            string templPath = _filePath;
            string newPath = _folderPath;
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    private static void assignValues(string filePath, string folderPath)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
        _folderPath = folderPath;
    }
}
```

The RequestInfo Designer code...
If you're new to C# you might not be familiar with this, just create a Designer File for RequestInfo and paste this in.

```
partial class RequestInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Designer variable used to keep track of non-visual components.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
    private System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog;
    private System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label filePath;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button fileBrowseButton;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button folderBrowseButton;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label folderPath;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button cancelButton;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button okButton;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes resources used by the form.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            if (components != null) {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is required for Windows Forms designer support.
    /// Do not change the method contents inside the source code editor. The Forms designer might
    /// not be able to load this method if it was changed manually.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.openFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        this.folderBrowserDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        this.filePath = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.fileBrowseButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.folderBrowseButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.folderPath = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.cancelButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.okButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // openFileDialog
        // 
        this.openFileDialog.FileName = "openFileDialog";
        this.openFileDialog.Filter = "CVD Files|*.cvd";
        // 
        // filePath
        // 
        this.filePath.AutoSize = true;
        this.filePath.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 17);
        this.filePath.Name = "filePath";
        this.filePath.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 13);
        this.filePath.TabIndex = 0;
        this.filePath.Text = "No File Selected";
        this.filePath.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        // 
        // fileBrowseButton
        // 
        this.fileBrowseButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.fileBrowseButton.Name = "fileBrowseButton";
        this.fileBrowseButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.fileBrowseButton.TabIndex = 1;
        this.fileBrowseButton.Text = "Browse";
        this.fileBrowseButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.fileBrowseButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.fileBrowseButton_Click);
        // 
        // folderBrowseButton
        // 
        this.folderBrowseButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 51);
        this.folderBrowseButton.Name = "folderBrowseButton";
        this.folderBrowseButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.folderBrowseButton.TabIndex = 2;
        this.folderBrowseButton.Text = "Browse";
        this.folderBrowseButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.folderBrowseButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.folderBrowseButton_Click);
        // 
        // folderPath
        // 
        this.folderPath.AutoSize = true;
        this.folderPath.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 56);
        this.folderPath.Name = "folderPath";
        this.folderPath.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(98, 13);
        this.folderPath.TabIndex = 3;
        this.folderPath.Text = "No Folder Selected";
        this.folderPath.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        // 
        // cancelButton
        // 
        this.cancelButton.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.cancelButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(546, 10);
        this.cancelButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.cancelButton.Name = "cancelButton";
        this.cancelButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.cancelButton.TabIndex = 4;
        this.cancelButton.Text = "Cancel";
        this.cancelButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.cancelButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cancelButton_Click);
        // 
        // okButton
        // 
        this.okButton.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.okButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(465, 10);
        this.okButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.okButton.Name = "okButton";
        this.okButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.okButton.TabIndex = 5;
        this.okButton.Text = "OK";
        this.okButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.okButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.okButton_Click);
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.AutoSize = true;
        this.panel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.okButton);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.cancelButton);
        this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 298);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 10, 0, 10);
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(633, 43);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 6;
        // 
        // panel2
        // 
        this.panel2.AutoSize = true;
        this.panel2.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.fileBrowseButton);
        this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.folderBrowseButton);
        this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.folderPath);
        this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.filePath);
        this.panel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
        this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(633, 298);
        this.panel2.TabIndex = 7;
        // 
        // RequestInfo
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(633, 341);
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 200);
        this.Name = "RequestInfo";
        this.Text = "RequestInfo";
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.panel2.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) that gives me a dialogue in the class library code. I will try to add what I need into this.

Let me know if anyone has any opinions on this. Thanks again for the help.